# Ionic App Built on Mac won’t build on Windows

Tags: windows, ionic-framework, ionic3

We developed the app on a Mac, initially. Moved the code over to a Windows 10 machine to compile to run on Windows. However, in the build process I'm getting this error at the end:

```
Command finished with error code 0: C:\windows\system32\reg.exe query,HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4.0,/v,MSBuildToolsPath
Found MSBuild v4.0 at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\
Using MSBuild v4.0 from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\
MSBuild v4.0 is not supported, aborting.
Error: AppPackages doesn't exists
```

Here's Ionic Info

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.3.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1
Ionic CLI        : 3.3.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.3.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.0
Cordova Platforms               : windows 5.0.0
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.3.0
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.10.3
OS         : Windows 10
Xcode      : not installed
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
```

We're using Visual Studio Community 2017. I've tried installing everything under the sun for VS and I can't seem to get past this. I've read tons of pages and sites, tried everything I can find and no go.

Not sure what to do next. I've thought about starting a new app on the Windows machine and just copy my code into and see if that works. It seems like a lot of wasted time to me though.

Comment: What is the command you're running?

Comment: We were running the **cordova build** command. Tried different variations of those command. It was even failing the build from within VS.

Comment: Are you trying to build a UWP app though? Or Android? Not really sure why it's trying to use msbuild in the first place.

Comment: Yes, trying to build a UWP app

Answer (score -1):

My advice on this is just a simple one. Install and run your project with Visual Studio Code. It was built and well suited for free and open frameworks like Ionic. This is what I work with everyday. When you do that give me a comment below if you have any problem.